# Black screen after starting the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, mobile-application

As the title suggests whenever i try to start the emulator i get a phone with a black screen and nothing happens, i've tried many online solutions but none seem to work.
My guess is that this happens because i'm trying to run it on a low spec computer but i'm not sure.[image: a]

This is a picture of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue wiping user data helped me..

Go to Android Virtual Device Manager->Select your device->Start->Check "Wipe user data"->Launch

Comment: may be a screenshot would help.. try putting a screenshot.